# Prove a symmetric operator $A$ is not self-adjoint has no self-adjoint extension

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

**Question**: Let $A$ be a symmetric operator on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Assume that $A$ is not self-adjoint but $\operatorname{Ran}(A-i) = \mathcal{H}$ or $\operatorname{Ran}(A+i) = \mathcal{H}$. Prove that $A$ has no self-adjoint extension.

**My attempt**: I know that I have to somehow use the fact that a self-adjoint operator $\tilde{A}$ has the property $\operatorname{Ran}(\tilde{A}-i) = \mathcal{H}$ and $\operatorname{Ran}(\tilde{A}+i) = \mathcal{H}$. So I assumed that it has a self-adjoint extension and tried to induce any contradiction. However, I couldn't find the connections and didn't find a way to proceed.

**Note**: I found something about the Deficiency Indices which seems to be the direct path to this exercise but this is not covered in class. I think this exercise should be very simple but I just can't find a way forward.

Comment: Your assumptions imply that A is closed, because $\operatorname{Ran}(A+iI)$ is closed. Moreover the defect spaces $\ker (A^*\pm iI)$  are trivial. Therefore A is self-adjoint, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concreteness, suppose that $\mathrm{Ran}(A+\mathrm{i})= H$. Let $\widetilde A$ be a self-adjoint extension of $A$. Since $A$ is not self-adjoint, the domain of $\widetilde A$ strictly contains that of $\widetilde A$. Let $x \in H$ be an element of the domain of $\widetilde A$ which is not in the domain of $A$. By surjectivity of $A + \mathrm{i}$, there exists $y$ in the domain of $A$ such that $(\widetilde A + \mathrm{i})x = (A + \mathrm{i})y$. Then $x-y$ is nonzero and is annhilated by $\widetilde A+\mathrm{i}$. This is a contradiction because a self-adjoint operator can not have a non-real eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have several questions, and it will be very helpful if you can answer!: 1. Is it because $x$ is an element of the domain of $\tilde{A}$ but not domain of $A$ and $\operatorname{Dom}(A) \subset \operatorname{Dom}(\tilde{A})$, then $x-y$ is nonzero? 2. What does it mean by $x-y$ is annhilated by $\tilde{A}+i$ and could you elaborate more on the last two sentences? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I assumed that x is not in the domain of $A$ but $y$ is in this domain. Therefore $x$ and $y$ can't be equal, i.e. $x-y$ is nonzero. Saying that $(\widetilde A + \mathrm{i})$ annihilates $x-y$ means that $(\widetilde A + \mathrm{i})(x-y)=0$ (note that $\widetilde A y = A y$ because $\widetilde A$ is an extension of $A$ and $y$ is in the domain of $A$). Putting all this together and defining $z=x-y$, we get that $z$ is a nonzero vector satisfying the eigenvalue equation $\widetilde A z = - \mathrm{i} z$. Can you see how this contradicts $\widetilde A$ being symmetric?